# Determine starter solenoid current

Tags: electrical, starter, solenoid

I found the following paper talking about various starter mechanisms: http://www.aeroelectric.com/articles/strtctr.pdf

I can find there that a starter solenoid can take something like 35A while it is enganging. I cannot really see what type of solenoid those numbers are based on. Are all starters using the same or similar solenoids? I cannot imagine they do.

The reason I am asking is that I have a starter motor that I want to use outside of an automobile and I need to find a reasonably sized relay to trigger the solenoid. Reading the paper above kinda bummed me out because my largest starter relay can handle a solenoid current of 30A.

In my example I have an alanko 439983 0.8kW starter and I would like to figure out several properties of the starter, like the no load current or specifically in this case the max current draw of the solenoid. I have gone through numerous sites for that starter motor including the manufacturers page but it seems impossible to get any more information than the number of teeth, flange size and other mechnical properties. There does not seem to be any electronics data sheet.

So my question is: Where does one normally find a reliable source of information regarding the electrical properties of a starter motor?

Comment: Your title states "starter solenoid", yet in the question portion you're asking about the starter motor. Could you please clarify your question or title so we know what you're actually asking about? As described in the paper, the solenoid draws only 8-10A of power to hold it while it is starting an engine, yet can draw up to 25A to get things started (surge Amperage). The 35A it is talking about really has nothing to do with how much it takes to run the solenoid. It has to do with the power through the solenoids. Solenoids in and of themselves are pretty much universal in how they work.

Comment: Wire a battery with ammeter in series to the starter solenoid female terminal (not the main battery connection to the starter solenoid) and starter case (ground). The ammeter should be capable of measuring at least 10 amps or more. Powering the solenoid should display amp draw.